# Display Excel column name

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

If my selected cell is  in columns 1, 2. 3. or 4, taking column D as an example, is there a way that I can display the contents of D2 in cell A1?

[And likewise for any of the other columns with the value in row 2 of the selected column].

[image: array2]

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it using macro, no way for it without macro.

Comment: Are you saying that D5 is the cell you've clicked on, and you want `2` from D2 to appear in A1?  If so, yeah, you need VBA.  There's no function you could use in a formula in A1 that could recognize what cell has been selected, and no formula in the selectable cells could plug a value into A1.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Target.EntireColumn.Cells(2)
    Range("A1").Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**